# Routing a host to Vagrant

Tags: vagrant

## Vagrant

I currently have a set up on my development computer that uses apache and the hosts file to point to different folders. I's worked great but I've just discovered vagrant. The only problem with using vagrant is I seem to loose all the ability to use internal domains.

Currently I'm using the hosts file for something like this:

- main.dev -> localhost -> /local/www/main/
- *.dev -> localhost -> /local/www/main/
- staging.dev -> staging server

Is there anyway of mapping those domains to my vagrant box for a particular app instead of having to go to `localhost:3000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can continue to use your hosts file. Let's say you [assigned your Vagrant VM](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/host_only_networking.html) the IP address 192.168.11.111. Whereas before your hosts file might have been

> 127.0.0.1 main.dev staging.dev

Now it would be

> 192.168.11.111 main.dev staging.dev

However, instead of editing your hosts file manually, there are vagrant plugins that will either edit your hosts file for you or run a local DNS server. Take a look at [vagrant-dns](https://github.com/BerlinVagrant/vagrant-dns) and [vagrant-hostmaster](https://github.com/mosaicxm/vagrant-hostmaster).

Answer (score 0):

Apache reverse proxy on your dev computer. You'll practically map `localhost:3000` to `localhost/onesite`.

or

You can use bridge networking for guest.